# What's causing AVMutableComposition to increase the size of video drastically? - iOS, Swift, AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, video, swift3, avmutablecomposition

Assuming that we have two video assets (AVAsset objects), let's call them **blank** and **main**, where **main** is a video of random limited length, let's say 2-5 minutes, and **blank** is always a 4 second video, we want to merge the videos in the following order:

**blank - main - blank**

```
    // Create AVMutableComposition Object.This object will hold our multiple AVMutableCompositionTrack.

    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

    let assets = [blank, main, blank]
    var totalTime : CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 0)
    var atTimeM: CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 0)

    Utils.log([blank.duration, main.duration])

    // VIDEO TRACK
    let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    for (index,asset) in assets.enumerated() {

        do {

            if index == 0 {
                atTimeM = kCMTimeZero
            } else {
                atTimeM = totalTime // <-- Use the total time for all the videos seen so far.
            }

            try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration), of: asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], at: atTimeM)

        } catch let error as NSError {
            Utils.log("error: \(error)")
        }

        totalTime = CMTimeAdd(totalTime, asset.duration)
    }

    // AUDIO TRACK
    let audioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    do {
        try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, main.duration), of: main.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0], at: blank.duration)
    } catch _ {
        completionHandler(nil, ErrorType(rawValue: "Unable to add audio in composition."))
        return
    }

    let outputURL = mainVideoObject.getDirectoryURL()?.appendingPathComponent("video-with-blank.mp4")

    guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1280x720) else {
        completionHandler(nil, ErrorType(rawValue: "Unable to create export session."))
        return
    }

    let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(blank.duration, CMTimeAdd(main.duration, blank.duration)))

    // Fixing orientation
    let firstLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
    let firstAssetTrack = blank.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
    firstLayerInstruction.setTransform(firstAssetTrack.preferredTransform, at: kCMTimeZero)
    firstLayerInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: blank.duration)

    let secondLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
    let secondAssetTrack = main.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
    var isSecondAssetPortrait = false
    let secondTransform = secondAssetTrack.preferredTransform
    if (secondTransform.a == 0 && secondTransform.b == 1.0 && secondTransform.c == -1.0 && secondTransform.d == 0) {
        isSecondAssetPortrait = true
    }
    if (secondTransform.a == 0 && secondTransform.b == -1.0 && secondTransform.c == 1.0 && secondTransform.d == 0) {
        isSecondAssetPortrait = true
    }
    secondLayerInstruction.setTransform(secondAssetTrack.preferredTransform, at: blank.duration)
    secondLayerInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: CMTimeAdd(blank.duration, main.duration))

    let thirdLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
    let thirdAssetTrack = blank.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
    thirdLayerInstruction.setTransform(thirdAssetTrack.preferredTransform, at: CMTimeAdd(blank.duration, main.duration))

    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [firstLayerInstruction, secondLayerInstruction, thirdLayerInstruction]

    var naturalSize = CGSize()
    if(isSecondAssetPortrait) {
        naturalSize = CGSize(width: secondAssetTrack.naturalSize.height, height: secondAssetTrack.naturalSize.width)
    } else {
        naturalSize = secondAssetTrack.naturalSize
    }

    let renderWidth = naturalSize.width
    let renderHeight = naturalSize.height

    let mainCompositionInst = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mainCompositionInst.instructions = [mainInstruction]
    mainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
    mainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSize(width: renderWidth, height: renderHeight)

    exporter.outputURL = outputURL
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    exporter.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst
    //exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    exporter.exportAsynchronously {
        if exporter.status == .completed {
            completionHandler(AVAsset(url: outputURL!), nil)
        } else {
            completionHandler(nil, ErrorType(rawValue: "Unable to export video."))
            if let error = exporter.error {
                Utils.log("Unable to export video. \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Assuming that the original video recorder for 5 minutes at 720p quality takes around 200MB of space, adding the 4s blank video on begining and end of the main video should not drastically change the size, and should finish processing very fast.

The result however is a video that's 2 to 2.5x the size of the original video (so 400 - 500 MB) and takes too long to process.

Please advise,

Thanks

Comment: can you please send me sample blank video file which you are used for appending in between.

Answer (score 3):

Here i have prepared a custom class where you can just pass your name of your videos and keep those video into to the bundle. Once you run your app it will generate a new video file as per your requirement and drop it into the application document directory path.

**Using Swift 4 i have prepared this demo**

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  SOVideoMergingDemo
//
//  Created by iOS Test User on 03/01/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Test User. Ltd. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer
import Photos
import AssetsLibrary
import AVKit


class ViewController : UIViewController {

    //--------------------------------------------------
    //MARK:
    //MARK: - IBOutlets
    //--------------------------------------------------




    //--------------------------------------------------
    //MARK:
    //MARK: - Properties
    //--------------------------------------------------

    var videoUrls : [URL]     = []
    var arrVideoAsset : [AVAsset] = []
    let video1 = "1"
    let video2 = "2"
    let outPutVideo = "MergedVideo.mp4"

    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)


    //--------------------------------------------------
    //MARK:
    //MARK: - Custom Methods
    //--------------------------------------------------

    func getVideoURL(forVideo : String) -> URL {
        let videoPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: forVideo, ofType:"mp4")
        let vidURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath!)
        return vidURL
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------

    func mergeVideos(arrVideoAsset : [AVAsset]) {

        let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

        //Tracks to insert in Composition for Merging
        // Create video tracks
        let firstTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID:  kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
        let secondTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID:  kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
         let thirdTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID:  kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

        do {
            try firstTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, arrVideoAsset[0].duration), of: arrVideoAsset[0].tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: kCMTimeZero)
        } catch _ {
            print("Failed to load first track")
        }

        do {
            try secondTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, arrVideoAsset[1].duration), of: arrVideoAsset[1].tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: arrVideoAsset[0].duration)
        } catch _ {
            print("Failed to load second track")
        }

        do {
            try thirdTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, arrVideoAsset[0].duration), of: arrVideoAsset[0].tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: arrVideoAsset[1].duration)
        } catch _ {
            print("Failed to load second track")
        }

        //This Instruciton is Created for Merging Video Tracks
        let compositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
        compositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,CMTimeAdd(arrVideoAsset[0].duration, CMTimeAdd(arrVideoAsset[1].duration, arrVideoAsset[2].duration)))

        //Creating Layer Instruction for Videos
        let firstInstruction = videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(firstTrack!, asset: arrVideoAsset[0])
        firstInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: arrVideoAsset[0].duration )
        let secondInstruction = videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(secondTrack!, asset: arrVideoAsset[1])
        secondInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: arrVideoAsset[1].duration)
        let thirdInstruction = videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(thirdTrack!, asset: arrVideoAsset[2])

        compositionInstruction.layerInstructions = [firstInstruction, secondInstruction,thirdInstruction]

        //By  Changing These Height and Width User can affect Size of Merged Video. Calucalte it Carefully and As per you needs
        let height = (Float((firstTrack?.naturalSize.height)!) < Float((secondTrack?.naturalSize.height)!)) ? firstTrack?.naturalSize.height : secondTrack?.naturalSize.height

        let width = (Float((firstTrack?.naturalSize.width)!) < Float((secondTrack?.naturalSize.width)!)) ? firstTrack?.naturalSize.width : secondTrack?.naturalSize.width

        let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        mainComposition.instructions = [compositionInstruction]
        mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
        mainComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width:width!,height: height!)

        let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset:mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
        exporter?.outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: getDocumentDirectoryPath() + "/" + outPutVideo)
        exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
        exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        exporter?.videoComposition = mainComposition
        print(self.getDocumentDirectoryPath())

        exporter?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if exporter?.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed {
                    do {
                        let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: exporter!.outputURL!)
                        try videoData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath : self.getDocumentDirectoryPath() + "/" + self.outPutVideo), options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
                    } catch {
                        print("Failed to Save video ===>>> \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }


                    //Uncomment This If you want to save video in Photos Library
//                    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
//                        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: (exporter?.outputURL)!)
//                    }, completionHandler: { (success, error) in
//                        if success {
//                            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
//                            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor.init(key:"creationDate", ascending: false)]
//                            _ = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options:fetchOptions).firstObject
//                        } else {
//                            print("Error in Saving File in Photo Libaray -> \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
//                        }
//                    })
                } else {
                    print("Error -> \(String(describing: exporter?.error?.localizedDescription))")
                }
            }
        })

    }

    //--------------------------------------------------

    //This Methiod is Used to Make Layer Instruction for Particular Video
    func videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(_ track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
        let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]
        let scale : CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y:1)
        instruction.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scale), at: kCMTimeZero)
        return instruction
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------

    func getDocumentDirectoryPath() -> String {
        let arrPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        return arrPaths[0]
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------
    //MARK:
    //MARK: - View Life Cycle Methods
    //--------------------------------------------------

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        //Prepare Video Assets
        arrVideoAsset.append(AVAsset(url:getVideoURL(forVideo:video1)))
        arrVideoAsset.append(AVAsset(url:getVideoURL(forVideo:video2)))
        arrVideoAsset.append(AVAsset(url:getVideoURL(forVideo:video1)))

        //Merge this Videos
        mergeVideos(arrVideoAsset:arrVideoAsset)
    }
}
```